# Finding Average per day, week and month

Tags: sql-server, average

I have this below query that shows list of claims with Assignment date and other columns.

**I wanted to find -

On average, how many assignments are sent from the field to OpenTemp every day, week, and month** any thoughts would be much appreciated. Thanks in Advance

```
    SELECT 
         A.[ClaimID]
          ,[ClaimNum]
          ,B.AssignedDate
          ,[ClaimReOpenDate]
          ,[ClaimOriginalReOpenDate]
           ,[AdjusterName]
          ,[Specialty]
          ,[Office]
          ,[Team]
          ,[Supervisor]
          ,[OpenforRD]
          ,[MaxRdDate]
          ,[MinRdDate]
          ,[CatCode]
      FROM tableA a
    left outer join  TableB b on A.ClaimID = B.ClaimID
      where ToUser like '%RD%'
      and FromUser like '%Field%'
     AND Specialty = 'RD' and RowIsCurrent  = 'Y'
      and DerivedClaimStatus in ('Open', 'Re-Open')
```

**Sample Data**

```
    ClaimID ClaimNum    AssignedDate        ClaimReOpenDate ClaimOriginalReOpenDate AdjusterName    Specialty   Office  Team            Supervisor  OpenforRD       MaxRdDate       MinRdDate   CatCode

    2334582 2334582     2018-06-22 10:52:51.283 NULL            NULL                Byers           RD          Akron   Akron RD Team 1  Tilley         1           2018-06-22      2018-06-22  NULL

    2273950 2273950     2018-02-05 11:49:07.933 NULL            NULL                Cannon          RD          Akron   Akron RD Team 2  Ailing         1           2018-02-05      2018-02-05  NULL

    2333064 2333064     2018-06-27 09:06:10.857 NULL            NULL                Murphy          RD          Akron   Akron RD Team 1  Tilley         1           2018-06-27      2018-06-27  NULL

    2303323 2303323     2018-03-29 13:49:48.730 NULL            NULL                Rothermel       RD          Akron   Akron RD Team 2  Ailing         1           2018-03-29      2018-03-29  NULL
```

Comment: Can you please share some sample data?

Comment: Expected results would be helpful too.

Comment: Hi. included the sample data. Thanks

Comment: @Larnu I'm looking for a one tow results that should show On average, how many assignments are sent from the field to OpenTemp every day, week, and month

Comment: So, for your sample data provided, what would that be?

Comment: Sounds like you just need to use some basic math with aggregation here (i.e. AVG). But it is not at all clear what you have for data or what you want as output. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: The average day is with respect to the month, which the number of days in each month varies.  The number of days in the last week of each month also varies.  For me- the easiest way is to import the dataset into PowerBI and use it as a reporting tool.  The AssignDate (Date) is joined to an imported dimdate table or a calculated table for dates (using DAX).  Then PowerBI's table visual can take the averages by the different granularity- day, week, and month.  You could also attempt something in pure SQL with a DimDate table by filtering after joining to DimDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        --  for week                                                              
       Select Avg(ClaimCount) from (             Select Count(1) AS ClaimCount  from    
       FROM tableA a
            left outer join  TableB b on A.ClaimID = B.ClaimID
            where ToUser like '%RD%'
  and FromUser like '%Field%'
 AND Specialty = 'RD' and RowIsCurrent  = 'Y'
  and DerivedClaimStatus in ('Open', 'Re-Open') 
   Group by  DATEPart(WK,AssignedDate))i                                             
      --- for month                                                                 
   Select Avg(ClaimCount) from (             Select Count(1) AS ClaimCount  from    
       FROM tableA a
            left outer join  TableB b on A.ClaimID = B.ClaimID
            where ToUser like '%RD%'
  and FromUser like '%Field%'
 AND Specialty = 'RD' and RowIsCurrent  = 'Y'
  and DerivedClaimStatus in ('Open', 'Re-Open') 
   Group by  DATEPart(MONTH,AssignedDate))i
```

Comment: See this query for week and month , change the group by to DATEPart(DAYOFYEAR,getdate()) for day

Comment: check now please

Comment: This query will give you avg of claims by week . for e.g. the week 1 the claims were 10 week2 were 12 then average of claims by week would be 12.If this is what you are looking for then the above query will work. if you are looking for each week avg for e.g. week 1 --> day1 [2] day2 [4]  week 2 day[1] 5 ,day[2] 7 then week1 will be 3 and week2 will be 6 , which case are you looking for?